# How to run all testcase of a file from other test file in nightwatch

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

I am trying to run a testfile which has multiple testcase inside it from another test file.
let's say, i have admin-registration.js test file which has multiple testcase in it. I have to run all the testcase of admin-registration.js from another testfile called main.js.

I am trying to do this in this way, but not able to do:

main.js

```
const testFiles = require('../tests/admin-registration');

module.exports = {
    "testcase1":testFiles
}
```

Although i am able to run one testcase of testFiles by specifying name with dot(.) sign. But I have to run all the test case of testFiles.

Comment: you are trying to invoke another test file from a test file that already has tests?

Comment: i am trying to execute all test cases of admin-registration file by invoking it into main.js

Answer (score 0):

Not understanding the use case on importing a test file into another test file.

You can group all your test cases into one file called admin-registration.js. Then run that file like this:

`npx nightwatch -e chrome tests/admin-registration.js`

You can group multiple test files into one folder then run it like this:

`npx nightwatch -e chrome tests/admin`

Assuming the test/admin folder has multiple test files ex. admin-registration.js, admin-login.js, admin-create-group.js and etc.